# Display the list of all the users in admin

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to display the list of all the existing users and their corresponding questions. I can't seem to figure out this code isn't working. I should be able to add a new question to the existing user.
In the models.py I have this

```
class Test(models.Model):

    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    question=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField('date_published')


def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user
```

In admin.py

```
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

     list_display = ('user', 'question', 'pub_date')
admin.site.register(Test, TestAdmin)
```

It displays all the fields when I hit add but doesn't save it.

Comment: Does it raise any errors? Code looks fine. It will show admin page for Test model, where you can add and edit "Test". You'll need to fill all three fields to be able to save it.

Comment: It does not raise any error but the page keeps loading and nothing happens. I'm able to fill all the three fields, neither can I save it nor I can open the change option. The page keeps loading..

Comment: It works fine without the user field though

Comment: You can try two things: change unicode method to return self.question and remove "user" from list_display. If it'll work after that add by one and see which is wrong.

Comment: Okay well I was supposed to delete the table first from MySQL before making any changes in the models. Now that I have set Debug to True, I can actually see the errors. It works, thanks!